# Getting Error Trying to get property of Non-Object

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I am getting an error trying to get property of non-object, I created role and user table and pass foreign key to the user table, no I want only authenticate and admin user access to the admin dashboard

I try different logic but non-work for me Here is my code

**UserModel** :

```
public function role(){
    return $this->belongsTo(\App\Role::class);
}
```

**RoleModel** :

```
public function users(){
    return $this->hasMany(\App\User::class);
}
```

**AdminController** :

```
public function __construct()
{
    return $this->middleware(['auth','CheckAdmin']);
}

public function index(){
    //$adminUsers = User::with('roles')->where('id',auth()->user()->id)->get();
    //dd($adminUsers);
    return view('backend.admin.index');
}
```

**CheckAdminMiddleware**:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(Auth::user()->role->name == 'Admin'){
        return redirect('/admin')->with('message', "Successfully Login");
    }
    return $next($request);

}
```

My UserTable:

```
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('role_id')->default(1);
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('username')->unique();
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->string('phone_no',15)->nullable();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->enum('status', [0,1])->default(1);
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->softDeletes();
```

my roleTable:

```
Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name')->unique();
    $table->boolean('deletable')->default(true);
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->softDeletes();
});
```

I am getting the error in middleware. what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `if (Auth::check()) { }` use auth::check before you use Auth::user in middleware.

Comment: @Laravel still same error in this line : if (Auth::user()->role->name == 'Admin')

Answer (score 0):

Because your `Auth::user()->role` return collection instead of an object.
You should call `Auth::user()->role['name']`.

Comment: Auth::user()->role['name] == "Admin" when i dd() this it return false everytime, even Admin is already there in database

Comment: Maybe you should check guard too. Ex: Auth::guard('web')->user();

Comment: Can you show me value of Auth::user()->role['name'] ?

Comment: dd(Auth::user()->role['name'] == "Admin");
Answer : false

Comment: Please show me only value `Auth::user()->role['name']`, not value of comparison.

Comment: dd(Auth::user()->role['name']) this giving me null.

Comment: Result show user is dont have any role. Check again your `user id` and in `role` table with that id.

Comment: i updated my question with include my tables information. please check it

Comment: i am doing a freaking stupid mistake, i write user_id instead of role_id -_-
now one more problem, it gives me to many redirect error.

Comment: Did you try this `Auth::user()->role()['name']` ?

Comment: yeah i try this. and this works, now the problem is it redirect teacher also to admin dashboard.

Comment: Collections are objects

Answer (score 0):

You're closest to get the result. So try these:

1. At first: remove "return" from __construct like this:

> ```
> public function __construct()
> { 
>     $this->middleware(['auth','CheckAdmin']); // without return keyword
> }
> ```

Check now.

2. Make sure you have registered that middleware in the end of $routeMiddleware (in "app\Http\Kernel.php") like this

> ```
> protected $routeMiddleware = [
>      // ...
>      'CheckAdmin'=> CheckAdminMiddleware::class,
> ];
> ```

And run "php artisan config:cache".

3. If it the same, then just remove "CheckAdmin" from __contstruct() like this:

> ```
> public function __construct()
> {
>     $this->middleware(['auth']);
> }
> ```

And attach that middleware in routes (instead of controller), like this:

```
Route::group([
    'as'     => 'admin.',
    'prefix'     => 'admin',
    'middleware' => [
        'checkAdmin', // THE THING
    ],
], function () {

    Route::get('dashboard', 'Admin\DashboardController@dashboard');
```

Comment: your answer help me some, but it still redirect to admin page when i login from teacher credentials

Comment: You need to improve the logic in middleware's handle() functions. For example if you have many roles, then you can write switch case under one middeware and return them to appropriate page. Or you can write multiple middlewares (as in your case) and strict acsesses for different clients. Sorry if comment not readable, now I just AFK

Answer (score 0):

if you are familiar with the laravel relations then you will know that `many-to-many` relations will returns the

`Illuminate\Support\Collection`

So you can use the Contains Method https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-contains

Paste the following Code into the **UserModel**

```
public function hasRole($role)
    {
        return $this->roles()->get()->pluck('name')->contains($role);
    }
```

And the Middleware Code

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(Auth::user()->hasRole('Admin')){
        return redirect('/admin')->with('message', "Successfully Login");
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

So we are getting the `roles of Auth User` and Checking it with **(Roles)** array that contains the Given **(Role)**